# How to integrate standard normal cdf to nth power

Tags: integration, statistics, normal-distribution

I'm struggling to find a way to integrate **$\Phi^n(a_nx + b)$** (I have values for $a_n$ and $b_n$)

I have got $(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{a_nx+b} \exp(-\frac{y^2}{2}) dy)^n$ but I am unsure on how to proceed.

Eventually I would need to show that this integral tends to $exp(-exp(-x))$ as $n \to \infty$. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

(Apologies for the poor format, I've not used MathJax before)

Comment: Maybe you could tell us what the sequences $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ are. An asymptotic expansion may be sufficient.

Comment: Section 4.1 here might be what you need https://arxiv.org/pdf/1507.05442.pdf

Comment: Apologies, I should have mentioned in the question.  $a_n = 39(2logn)^{-1/2}$ and $b_n = 39(2logn)^{1/2} - \frac{39(2logn)^{-1/2}}{2}[loglogn +log(4\pi)] $ I have done a course of extreme value theory so I'm not sure asymptotic expansion is something I'd be looking to do, thanks for the suggestion though! Is there a way to perhaps the simplify the integral?